# Pass property name as parameter

Tags: c#

I have the following class

```
public class School
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have this method

```
public bool Evaluate(??)
{
    var school = DbContext.Schools.FirstOrDefault();
    return school.??.Any(/*some expresions*/)
}
```

I should be able to pass a value in ?? and use it so that i can use both

```
return school.Students.Any(/*some expresions*/)
return school.Teachers.Any(/*some expresions*/)
```

So how can i replace the question marks with Students or Teachers ?

**Edit:**

```
public class Student 
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool Registered { get; set; }
    public bool Passed { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool CanEvaluate { get; set; }
    public bool Validator { get; set; }
}


public class DynamicCheckTest
{
    public bool MyExpression<T>(List<T> items, string name,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return items.Any(x => expression.Compile()(x));
    }
}

public static bool Check<T>(this List<T> items, Func<T, bool> compiledExp)
{
    return items.Any(x => compiledExp(x));
}

Students.Check(x => x.Name == "Mike" &&  x.Registered); // example
Teachers.Check(x => x.Name == "Jack" &&  x.CanEvaluate);// example
```

Now i have to pass the school along which contains both Students and Teachers
But i don't know which one will be called in advance

Comment: Do you have control over the definitions of `Student` and `Teacher`?

Comment: Do both classes derive from the same base class?

Comment: No you shouldn't because the types of `Student` and `Teacher` are different.  What will "some expressions" be?  Because whatever it is, it must be something that can apply to either a `Student` or a `Teacher`.  This is why you are being asked about whether they share a base class or common interface.

Comment: Can you post the declarations for Teacher and Student?

Comment: Would you consider a lambda?  Instead of somehow calling `Evaluate("Students")` you can instead call `Evaluate(school => school.Students)` And then the `Evaluate` method can invoke the lambda on the school to get the desired collection.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the "Pass property name as parameter" request, you could use reflection for that, but I don't think that's a good way to go.  Instead, a [`Func<School, List<TElement>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-2) could be used to select the desired `List<>` property to evaluate...

```cs
public bool Evaluate<TElement>(Func<School, List<TElement>> listSelector)
    where TElement : Person
{
    School school = DbContext.Schools.FirstOrDefault();
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

    return listSelector(school)
        // For example, check if today is the birthday of anyone in the selected list
        .Any(person => person.DateOfBirth.Month == today.Month && person.DateOfBirth.Day == today.Day);
}
```

As @Enigmativity points out, the [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) is necessary in order to pass much of a meaningful condition to `Any()`, which also assumes/requires that `Student` and `Teacher` have common ancestry, like this...

```cs
public abstract class Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
}
```

You'd then use a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) to specify the desired `List<>`...

```cs
bool isAnyStudentsBirthday = Evaluate(school => school.Students);
bool isAnyTeachersBirthday = Evaluate(school => school.Teachers);
```

This will work as long as the members you want `Any()` to consider are available in the constrained type (i.e. `Person`).  If you wanted to filter using members specific to the `Student` or `Teacher` class, your best bet would be to use an approach like [@Enigmativity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461430/150605), where the filter itself is a parameter and receives the same derived type as the selected `List<>` stores.

Note that if you ever want to use `Evaluate()` with some other collection property of `School` that is not specifically `List<>`, or just knowing that all `Any()` needs is an `IEnumerable<>`, you could change the return type (last [type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)) of the `Func<>` to something less-restrictive...

```cs
Func<School, IList<TElement>>
Func<School, ICollection<TElement>>
Func<School, IEnumerable<TElement>>
```

Comment: What could `/*some expresions*/` be if you have `List<TElement>` at compile-time? All the compiler can possibly know about `TElement` is that it is an `object`. The expressions would by pretty boring.

Comment: The author put `/*some expresions*/` which, to me, means "it's not important what's here" so I just passed it through in my code.  Does that _really_ mean my answer qualifies as "not useful" in your eyes when it still has the key point of using a type parameter, same as your later answer?  If we later find out that `Student` and `Teacher` share a common base type for which a meaningful condition _could_ be embedded in `Evaluate()` I suppose I should downvote your answer for being needlessly complicated?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer can only rely on `TElement` being an `object` - there are no `/*some expresions*/` that makes the answer useful. And even if they shared a common base type that doesn't mean that there are common properties that allow meaningful code to be written. You would likely then need to modify your signature to be `bool Evaluate<TElement>(Func<School, List<TElement>> listSelector) where TElement : CommonBaseType`. You would still need to then have a `Func<TElement, bool>` parameter to make it useful.

Comment: I would be interested in see how you would flesh your code out assuming that there is a common base type. Could you add that as an extended answer?

Comment: Yes, I realize that now that a type constraint would be needed to make a fixed filter work.  Fair enough.  Still, that seems like I'm being punished for not filling in the author's intentional blank, and I'd also point out that `.Any(/*some expresions*/);`, taken literally, is the same as `.Any();`, which is valid and meaningful.

Comment: I would have to say that `.Any(/*some expresions*/)` would rule out `.Any()` unless it were written as `.Any(/*no expresions*/)`. I think saying `some` means there is something there. That's the crux of for me. I think the OP just wrote very loose pseudo code so I think we need to infer the meaning.

Comment: @BACON +1 for SOLID principle. Enigmativity is also a good solution but it is best used for different scenario that encapsulation is not possible.

Comment: Thank you i will try your solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method:

```
public bool Evaluate<T>(Func<School, List<T>> project, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    var school = DbContext.Schools.FirstOrDefault();
    return project(school).Any(filter);
}
```

If we assume that the implementation of `Student` and `Teacher` are this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string Subject;
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
bool hasFred = Evaluate(school => school.Students, student => student.Name == "Fred Nerk");
bool teachArt = Evaluate(school => school.Teachers, teacher => teacher.Subject == "Art");
```

Comment: Would you consider changing `s` to `school`, `s` to `student`, and `t` to `teacher` where appropriate for clarity?

Comment: @Wyck - No problem. It makes the line a little too long for SO to display without a scrollbar, but that's not too bad.

Comment: Change biology to art and it'll fit.  ;)

Comment: @Wyck - Smart thinking!